# Redirect using:window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using `window.location.href` to redirect a user to some page if a condition is met. I've placed `window.location.href` inside an `if` block only, without an `else` block for it. When I execute my code, although the redirection works, but the code just after the `if` block also gets executed. Shouldn't the execution of the code of the page halt as soon as it is redirected to some other page?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If the (if condition) after window.location.href is valid it will be executed as window.location.href takes some time to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `abort`to stop the script after the `if` statement.

Like this:

```
if(condition) {
   window.location.href = 'somewhere.com';
   abort; // it will stop the code below the if statement, IF the condition is true.
} 
..
some other code
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Write exit();  after the window.location.href = 'abc.com';..This will redirect the page and the code just after window.location.href will not execute.